# Mysql/php sort by second word of varchar

Tags: sql, mysql, cpu-word

I have one VARCHAR(name with firstname and surname for example: John Snow) in `mysql` database. I want sort by surname(alphabetically).

Can I add something like 'ORDER BY SECOND WORD' to SQL request?

Comment: What about someone named "Arthur C. Clarke", "Anna da Silva" or "Oscar De La Hoya"?

Comment: No. Create two fields, first; sur; sort on sur field.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  One method would be:

```
order by substring_index(name, ' ', -1)
```

Note that this may not work for suffixes. It also might not work for middle names.  On the other hand, titles might throw off an exact second word match, but this will work for those.

Answer (score 1):

The question specifically asks to sort by the "SECOND WORD".  Some answers given sort by the last word, not the second word. To sort by the second word of the field "fullname", use the below...

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ' ', 2), ' ', -1)
```

In more general terms, to select the N-th value from the string VALUES that contains values separated by delimiter DELIM, use the below...

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( VALUES, DELIM, N ), DELIM, -1 )
```

For more information, refer to https://www.giannistsakiris.com/2015/01/23/mysql-select-the-n-th-element-from-a-delimiter-separated-value-set/

Answer (score 0):

If you are guaranteed a single space between firstname and lastname you may be able to do something like

```
select 
[fullname]
, SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ' ', 1) as [firstname]
, SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ' ', -1) as [lastname]
from <table>
order by [lastname]
```

Fill in the proper table and column names.

Answer (score 0):

As others already mentioned, you can use the `substring_index` function to order the results using the part after the first space.

In your case `ORDER BY SECOND WORD` would translate to `ORDER BY substring_index(name, ' ', -1)`

But I wouldn't do that because:

1. It's not reliable since in real life, you can't guarantee that all the names in your dataset will follow the `FIRST_NAME<space>LAST_NAME` format.
2. It can be quite slow depending on your dataset size.

If you can change the schema of database, it's preferable to have two separate columns for first and last names (and probably middle name). This would deal with #1 since you'll be guaranteed the ordering is done on the last name and not a middle name. To solve #2, you can always create a B-tree index on the last name column to speed the ordering.